# Magento Go Shopping Cart Integration

Tags: php, magento, shopping-cart

I have a store that uses the Magento Community edition. I want to use Magento Go for my next store, and I was wondering if it was possible to integrate the shopping cart I use for my current store into my new store through Magento Go. I know it said that Magento Go took care of server space etc, and I host my current stores on GoDaddy. Would that be an issue?

Comment: not a programming question, and no, you won't be able to integrate anything on Magento Go

Answer (score 0):

Magento Go platform will be shut down in February 2015. You will not be able to open an account with them any more.